# Why is a numeric handle sometimes referred to as a "name"?

Tags: c, semantics, naming

I've noticed in various C libraries, and most notably in the OpenGL API, that the word "name" is used to describe a simple integer value (often unsigned); [example here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetTexParameter.xhtml). It sounds like what in other areas of development might be called an **id** (database keys) or a **handle** (file descriptors), which is why I'm surprised at the absence of these terms *which I would ordinarily prefer over "name" since "name" conflicts with string identifiers or descriptions*. I'm guessing the reasons to be historical.

Can anyone enlighten me with regard to the background of this term and whether or not it is still considered to be in vogue in the C community?

**NB** This is NOT a question about OpenGL so please could we keep the answers general - thanks.

Comment: I fail to understand, why is this important, useful?

Comment: In an abstract sense a handle is a name for the thing it refers to.

Comment: @iharob History is how we got to where we are today (with C), so it matters. I also would like to write idiomatic C if possible.

Comment: @Barmar So why not use one of the other terms I mentioned? They are a better fit.

Comment: Personal choice on the part of the designer.

Comment: @Barmar With due respect, are you sure you aren't speculating?

Comment: Perhaps the term "name" betrays a focus on the source code, rather than on its meaning.  Taking your OpenGL example, the parameters referred to as names are of enumerated types, and one would normally expect the values given in source code to be expressed in terms of the associated enumeration constants (`GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL`, `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R`, etc.), which are alphanumeric in a source code sense.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Now that is an insightful viewpoint, and well-worded. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I was speculating. What kind of answer did you expect for this question? You're asking why some programmer in the past happened to choose a particular term in documentation. We're not mind readers.

Comment: You also only gave one example, but asked for a general answer. @JohnBollinger's answer is correct for OpenGL, but you implied that there are other libraries like this. I took your word for it that the _name_ parameter is a handle.

Comment: @Barmar No need to get defensive. As I said, this has been seen in several libraries that I've used. I assume it is not an uncommon phenomenon. So no, I don't think it's entirely down to speculation.

Comment: The point is that there are lots of different ways to call things, and different programmers choose different ones. For instance, PHP calls handles _resources_.

Comment: @Barmar Correct, and I am asking whether there is any overriding _reason_ why _in C_ this term "name" is not infrequently used. That question still stands, and I hope to receive more solid answers like John's. If there aren't any, no problem, but telling me "it was a design choice" is not a useful answer and is something I could have told myself.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer, I'm not sure *how* common such design choices are, at least these days, but I'm inclined to guess "not very".  Notwithstanding my speculation about the nature of such usage, Barmar is quite right: a name is an identifier, and so it's not so hard to accept an identifier as a name.  Also, punniness in coding was more common back in the day, so there may be a bit of that factoring in.

Comment: Do you have a better example of wider use? Effectively the API you linked to is creating a structure in the memory space of the OpenGL implementation, and you are querying the fields of that struct using an enumeration to indicate which field; the documentation refers to this as 'symbolic name' which is the same as what the code to query of the struct in the program memory space would be `x = texture.border_color` became `glGetTexParam(target,texture, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, &x)` so the enum parameter is an equivalent to the name of the field

Comment: @PeteKirkham Appreciate the comment. I wish I could, now, locate the other libraries I've seen with this in use (I believe there were two that I've seen besides OpenGL). Perhaps I should have waited to ask this question _after_ finding those references! I do find the reference to a _struct member / identifier_ as a _name_ unusual (academic, perhaps?), but perhaps this was more common back in the day.

Comment: @PeteKirkham You've actually answered my question. I looked up "symbolic name" and I see that this isn't just something referred to in the OpenGL literature, but is in fact a broader term used around C. If you would like to put this as an answer, I will accept it. Seems trivial, but it works for me, insofar as the connection between macros and enums. P.S. [Link](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=vB3hWk4YcGcC&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=c+%22symbolic+name%22&source=bl&ots=X9HRY9SWBU&sig=cOlL09ops4Q-M8gdt4BFsNO-5zE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=c%20%22symbolic%20name%22&f=false) in this regard.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I know I am a physicist, it's all about history. No one would understand wher quantum mechanincs comes from it they don't know the history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively the API you linked to is creating a structure in the memory space of the OpenGL implementation, and you are querying the fields of that struct using an enumeration to indicate which field. The documentation refers to this as 'symbolic name' which is what the equivalent token in the code to query of the struct in the program memory space would be: 
`x = texture.border_color` becomes `glGetTexParam(target, texture, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, &x)`

so the enum parameter `GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR` is an equivalent to the name of the field's symbolic name `border_color`

Comment: Just to add here for others reading this that _name_ is a shortened form of _symbolic name_ which is a de facto term in use in C literature (although perhaps uncommonly used). See this [link](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=vB3hWk4YcGcC&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=c+%22symbolic+name%22&source=bl&ots=X9HRY9SWBU&sig=cOlL09ops4Q-M8gdt4BFsNO-5zE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=c%20%22symbolic%20name%22&f=false) for an example - page 35 of "Solutions to Programming in C and Numerical Analysis". Thanks Pete for the leg up.